# Pipeline azure devops of power bi transformation pbip to pbix

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, cicd

Using Azure DevOps in a Power BI deployment pipeline, is it possible to transform the folders of the `.pbip` format to `.pbix` format, in order to deploy the Power bi directly from the `.pbip` format?

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Comment: Sorry, it did help me, it confirmed that there was no way to do it.
I am having problems in my deployments because when uploading as pbix it steps on the dataset and it does not let me update the data automatically and I was looking for other upload methods to see if the problem is solved, but I was running out of options.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that Azure DevOps  does not support converting Power Bi .pbip files to .pbix files.

Refer to this doc: [Power BI Desktop projects (PREVIEW)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/projects/projects-overview#frequently-asked-questions)

> Question: Can I convert PBIX into PBIP and vice-versa programmatically?

> Answer: No. You can only convert a PBIX into a PBIP and vice-versa using Power BI Desktop's File > Save as.

Since the programming method cannot be used, the file cannot be converted directly in Azure DevOps.

If you need to convert the .pbip file to .pbix, you only can achieve it via Power BI Desktop.